# How to create multiple elements by DOM in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dom-events

I have an HTML code like this:

```
<div> box 1 </div> // my whole code
```

And I want to create multi-element  **in div box 1**  with inside `img` and `text` and after the `div box 1`  I want to create  another `div` , `img`, and `text`.

The illustration I wanted is like this :

```
<div>
  box 1  // my whole  code before add those below
  <img> icon.jpg </img>
  <h1> some text </h1>
</div>
  
<div>
  box 2
  <img> icon.jpg </img>
  <h1> some text </h1>
</div>
  
<div>
  box 3
  <img> icon.jpg </img>
  <h1> some text </h1>  
</div>
```

I make an event on the function to show the box and icon and some text inside the box,

here is my code:

```
const clickSearch = document.querySelector(".btn0").addEventListener("click",() => {
  let ValuE  = document.querySelector("#inPut").value
  let putDiv   = document.createElement("div")
  putDiv.id = "flex-container-01"
  putDiv.textContent = ValuE
      
  let addD = document.querySelector(".flex-container")
  addD.appendChild(putDiv)
      
  let imgage = document.createElement("img")
    image.src  = "icon.gif"
    let divDone = document.querySelector("#flex-container-01")
  divDone.after(image)
})
```

**but** My code was added like this on HTML:

```
<div> box 1 </div> // my whole code 

<img>  icon.jpg </img>
<img>  icon.jpg </img>
<img>  icon.jpg </img>

<h1> text </h1>
<h1> text </h1>
<h1> text </h1>

<div> box 2 </div>
<div> box 3 </div>
<div> box 4 </div>
```

Comment: What is your actual question/problem here? None of the elements you query via class or id exist in your given HTML “example”, so please fix that and give a _proper_ [mcve].

Comment: my issue is on the above text, the below code was wrong and that is why i need some help

Comment: Again, please give us a _proper_ example, if you want our help. _“I want to create multi-element  in div box 1 and after the div box 1 also”_ - and based on what do you decide what goes _into_ that element, and what comes _after_?

Comment: @misorude i want to add the `div` and the inside is `img` and `text` , and then create another `div` again with  `img` and `text`

Comment: @JaromandaX look at the illustration i want, 

my code on HTML is only `div` box 1

Comment: I am not going to respond any more until you make the effort of providing a proper, run-able example to begin with.

Comment: @JaromandaX dit you mean that i use class ??

Comment: @misorude i edited it

Comment: is that mean i should use tagname or the element ? @JaromandaX

Comment: did u see the bottom code?? that is the result of my code after make that function click, @JaromandaX

Comment: Sorry, had to give up trying

Comment: u said that you didnt see btn0 class  on HTML, i wrote that on js, ,

my html only has the `div` box 1 , @JaromandaX

Comment: `u said that you didnt see btn0 class on HTML` correct - look at the HTML in your question ... where is `<input type="button" class="btn0">` or `<button class="btn0">` ... or `<input id="inPut">` or `<div class="flex-container">` - nowhere ... so how does the javascript relate to the code you posted - hint: not at all

Comment: is that mean the code i wrote bad ? @JaromandaX :(

Comment: well, yes, for the reasons I tried to tell you (though you ignored it) - your code (if it worked at all) would mean every image `divDone.after(image)` is placed after the first `"flex-container-01"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out this [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/yRVRYZ?editors=1011)

The code in my example will generate the following HTML three times:

```
<div id="...">
 box number
 <img src="..."></img>
 <h1>...</h1>
</div>
```

```js
window.onload = ()=>{
  let newDiv;
  let newImage;
  let newHeader;
  let newHeaderText;
  let newTextNode;
  let lineBreak;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // create the container div
    newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    // create a new img element
    newImage = document.createElement('img');
    // create a new header element
    newHeader = document.createElement('h1');
    // create the text for the header element above
    newHeaderText = document.createTextNode('some text');
    // some text based on your example
    newTextNode = document.createTextNode(`Box ${i + 1}`);
    // a line break (br)
    lineBreak = document.createElement('br');
    
    // assign an id to the div
    newDiv.id = `flex-container-${i}`;
    // assign the source of the img element
    newImage.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/32x32';
    
    // put that "box-[num]" text inside the div
    newDiv.appendChild(newTextNode);
    
    // add in the line break
    // newDiv.appendChild(lineBreak);
    
    // put the img element inside the div
    newDiv.appendChild(newImage);
    // put the headerText inside the h1 element
    newHeader.appendChild(newHeaderText);
    // put the header element inside the container div
    newDiv.appendChild(newHeader);
    // put the newly created div inside the body of our page (or document)
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
  }
};
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  </body>
<html>
```

If you want this generation to happen on a click event, just put the code inside the proper event handler instead of `window.onload`:)